How are these "clearly" the eigenfunctions in $\theta$?
Full context is a bit lengthy, but I've provided all of it below:
From Haberman section 7.10, we start with the 3-D wave equation (and it's associated BCs) for a spherical system where $\theta$ is the polar angle, and $\phi$ is the angle from the z-axis:
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = c^2 \nabla^2 u \cases{u(a,\theta,\phi,t) = 0 \\ u(r,\theta,\phi,0 = F(r,\theta,\phi) \\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(r,\theta,\phi,0) = G(r,\phi,\theta)}$$
$u = w(r,\theta,\phi)h(t)$
$$\tag{2a}\frac{d^2 h}{dt^2}+\lambda c^2 h = 0$$ $$\tag{2b}\nabla^2w+\lambda w = 0$$
Focusing on (2b) and applying the Laplacian in spherical coordinates we have:
$$\tag{3}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\Big(r^2\frac{\partial w}{\partial r}\Big) + \frac{1}{\sin\phi}\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}\Big(\sin\phi\frac{\partial w}{\partial \phi}\Big) + \frac{1}{\sin^2 \phi}\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial \theta^2} + r^2\lambda w = 0$$
And from here, we can then plug in
Plugging in $w = f(r)q(\theta)g(\phi)$ and separating (as well as creating a new separation constant, k) yields:
$$\tag{4}\frac{1}{f}\frac{d}{d r}\Big(r^2\frac{d f}{d r}\Big) + r^2\lambda = -\frac{1}{g\sin\phi}\frac{d}{d\phi}\Big(\sin\phi\frac{d g}{\partial \phi}\Big) - \frac{1}{w\sin^2 \phi}\boxed{\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial \theta^2}} = k$$
Where I've boxed the term $\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial \theta^2}$ to emphasize that this is where my point of confusion arises. According to Haberman, "... since the coefficients" in (4) "do not depend on $\theta$ and $w$ is periodic in $\theta$ with period 2$\pi$, we note that it is clear that the eigenfunctions in $\theta$ are $\cos(m\theta)$ and $\sin(m\theta)$".
I'm confused because I recognize eigenfunctions as functions of eigenvalues which satisfy the homogeneous BCs, so how are these eigenfunctions along $\theta$ accurate representations of the $q(\theta)$ if we don't have homogeneity along $\theta$? Based on the BCs, we have homogeneity along $r=a$, no?

NOTE: m is also a "separation constant" or an eigenvalue, meaning that when we apply a linear combination of these eigenfunctions $q(\theta) = c_1\cos(m\theta)+c_2\sin(m\theta)$ and plug this into (4), the boxed term becomes $\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial \theta^2}=-m^2 w$, we now have 3 separation constants.

$\theta$ is the polar angle and so $(r,\theta,\phi)$ and $(r,\theta+2\pi,\phi)$ should be the same point and so any function defined on this cylindrical coordinate system should give the same value. $w(r,\theta,\phi)=w(r,\theta+2\pi,\phi)$. Thus you get that $q$ must be $2\pi$ periodic.

@Tucker This sounds familiar to one of the conventions I've since forgotten since I took PDEs in college. So if the solution, $q$, is known to be 2$\pi$ periodic, then it can be represented by the eigenfunctions $\cos(k \theta)$ and $\sin(k\theta)$? Is that right?

Essentially. There is a bit more to it, in that if you introduce a separation constant in the right way then you have $d^{2}q/d\theta^{2}=\mu q$, similar to what you did in your NOTE but with $\mu=-m^{2}$.

One can investigate if $\mu>0$ can give $2\pi$ periodic functions (the answer is no). One can investigate if $\mu=0$ can give$ 2\pi$ periodic functions (here the answer is yes for a constant eigenfunction). And finally for $\mu<0$ one can investigate if one can obtain $2\pi$ periodic functions and the answer is yes, provided $\mu=-m^{2}$ for $m=1,2,\dots$.

Imposing $2\pi$ periodicity rules out $\mu>0$ eigenvalues and then restricts eigenvalues to $\mu=-m^{2}$ for $m=0,1,2,\dots$ and then you get the specific eigenfunctions. $\cos(m,\theta)$, $\sin(m,\theta)$ and constant functions. Hope this is helpful.
